# Postgres find by hstore key / value

Tags: postgresql, hstore

I have a table

```
create table device_entity
(
    id       uuid not null primary key,
    name     varchar(255),
    metadata hstore
);
```

This table has entries with 'country' = 'uk' in the metadata field.

This query returns all entries where the key 'country' is present in the metadata field.

```
SELECT * from device_entity where metadata ? 'country'
```

How can I select all entries where the key 'country' = 'uk'?

Comment: Use the `->` [operator](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/hstore.html#id-1.11.7.25.6)  - but nowadays I would prefer a jsonb column over hstore

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT * from device_entity where (metadata -> 'country') = 'uk';
```

This query will probably have quite slow performance which can probably be improved significantly by deploying the right inverted index.

Comment: No need for an "inverted index". A B-Tree index on the expression should work just fine

Comment: Of course, a dedicated column "country" in the table would be best for ease of use, index, and performance.

Comment: b-tree would work if this is the only interesting key